# SFTP with Gaufrette and Phpseclib can't read files

Tags: symfony, sftp, phpseclib, gaufrette

I am trying to get a json file in a SFTP server from a Symfony2 command. I use [KnpGaufretteBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) and the [phpseclib-sftp](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle#phpseclib-sftp-phpseclib_sftp) adapter.

I have on my computer a running SFTP server, I can connect it with filezilla and list/read files so I do not think there is a permission issue.

The problem is the connection work, I can list the files with

```
$sftpService->getExec()->run("ls")
```

But I can't with

```
$sftpService->getSftp()->listDirectory(".")
```

I can create a directory but not list it.. and I can't read the files. Here is my test code:

```
$sftpService = $this->getContainer()->get("phpseclib_sftp");
dump($sftpService->getExec()->run("ls")); //file "test.txt" exist
$sftp = $sftpService->getSftp();
dump($sftp->exists("test.txt")); //false
dump($sftp->read("test.txt")); //false
dump($sftp->mkdir("testMkdir")); //true
dump($sftpService->getExec()->run("ls")); //the new directory exist
dump($sftp->listDirectory("testMkdir")); //false
```

And here is the output:
[image: Console output]

And the permissions of the base folder:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sftp_user  staff  11  6 oct 10:31 test.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 sftp_user  staff  68  6 oct 10:56 testMkdir
```

Here is the warning for the `read` function
[image]

Edit: I can read the file with `$sftpService->getExec()->run("cat test.txt"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it's seems like for SFTP urls (ssh2.STFP://...) I need to use the absolute path, the base folder of my ftp user does not work, so it's working with:

```
$sftp->read($sftp->realpath("test.txt"))
```